# Return main function in sub function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I create multiple sub functions to process data and want to return the main function, once any nested function meets some condition. Then, the multiprocessing can continue the processes.

Here's a simple example:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool


def program1(num):
    num += 1
    return num

def program2(num):
    num += 1
    return num

def program3(num):
    num += 1
    return num

def main(num):
    num = program1(num)
    if num %2 != 0:
        return
    else:
        num = program2(num)
        if num %3 != 0:
            return
        else:
            num = program3(num)
            print(num)
            return num

pool = Pool(4)
nums = range(8)
pool.map(main, nums)
```

Because there're multiple programs, it will make the code looks quite long ...
Is it possible to wrap the if condition in each nested function?
Then I can just use

```
def main(num):
    num = program1(num)
    num = program2(num)
    num = program3(num)
```

Note that please don't care or simplify the data process hah. This is just an example to show the processes.

Comment: `multiprocessing` creates processes, not threads and there are no nested functions in your code — so your question is unclear.

Comment: @martineau Thanks. It should be `processes`. For nested functions, I mean these functions in the main function. | Updated

Comment: You can't do what you want because it would defeat the purpose of concurrently running the 3 subfunctions. Overall it looks like the processing being done is serial in nature because each subprocess depends on the results of an earlier one (except for the first of course).

Comment: @martineau Yes, only the first one is in parallel.

Comment: Note that the purpose isn't running all of the sub-functions. It should be skipping the following sub-functions once the condition is met.

Comment: Yes, I understand that — it's still a serial process that prevents it from being parallelized (which requires *independent* processes).